# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__cxa_finalize" referenced by "/system/lib/libdl.so"

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Up until Android 6, we had a working version of application, which was written using Qt Android, starting from Android 6 in Nexus device we are seeing strange error

`dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__cxa_finalize" referenced by "/system/lib/libdl.so"`

and application crashes.

```
objdump -T ourlibrary.so
...
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000 __cxa_finalize
...
```

tested with `-lc` flag in order to link libc.so, couldn't help, without it same problem.

other dependant libraries while building: `libgnustl_shared.so`

in order to cheat compiler we have added

```
extern "C" int __cxa_finalize(void*); // { empty body somewhere in .cpp file }
```

didn't help, could someone point into the problem?
Note: this was fully working until Android 6 (Marshmallow)

**UPD1:** api version `android-9`, architecture `arm`, qt android compilation `armv5`, toolchain version `4.9`

**UPD2:** some other libraries are showing glibc version

`00000000  w   DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_finalize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the same error when running my application. Do you have:

```
System.loadLibrary("dl");
```

Located in your code somewhere? If so, what I did to make my code run on 6 and <6 was to catch and ignore the UnsatisfiedLinkError exception thrown by 6 when trying to load the library.

Comment: I would add, if you don't have this explicit load, but have the crash, then add this explicit load of **libdl** early enough, and `try … catch` this exception.

Comment: removed `System.loadLibrary("dl")` and it started working fine